# Commands output to xconsole how?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

What I wants to do is to use xconsole to get the output of some user commands.
Basically as a regular user, I wanto concentrate my some commands outputs in xconsole so I will have a common place to get them. I use several terminals so this is the reason I want a common place for all the outputs.
The workaround at the moment is to call to my commands using the next alias in csh:

```
alias myCommand >& /tmp/console
```

Then I launch xconsole with the next command:

```
xconsole -file /tmp/console -daemon -notify -saveLines 1000
```

So for every command I need to send to xconsole I make a similar alias.
My problem is that this is opening a regular file I think, not a block or char device like /dev/console.
and sometimes seems that txconsole  stops to output stuff, I prefer to be able to create my own char device and output my stuff there, but trying to do it with mknod outside /dev returns me an error.
There is any way to create char devices in you user space?
Is the strategy I am using the best? or there are better alternative to get a common place for user comands output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a normal file for --file, it looks like just about every distribution creates a named pipe /dev/xconsole for this purpose, you can make one yourself with `mknod /tmp/console p`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think /dev/console is a character device, why did you put mknod in p mode to create a FIFE device, rather than c for character?

Comment: Because you can't go around just making up random devices, but you can make random FIFOs.  Normal users can't make device entries either, even if the major/minor device numbers exist (imagine the chaos if users could just create /dev/kmem with read and write permission!)